# Is the Bone Armour skill from Bone Barrier ascendancy skill tagged as "minion"?

Tags: path-of-exile

Normally skill gems tell you what their tags are so you know which support gems apply to them and whatnot, but since Bone Armour is granted as a result of allocating the ascendancy point for Bone Barrier, it doesn't seem like I have a way of seeing what the tags are.

What tags are on the Bone Armour skill? I was hoping that if it was tagged Minion I could use it in conjunction with "If you have used a minion skill recently..." effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to a [developer reply](https://www.reddit.com/r/pathofexile/comments/czot6y/summoner_things_that_we_still_could_use_info_on/ez29wsg/?context=3), Bone Armour is tagged as Duration, Guard, Minion, although it's not affected by global +1 to gem level items. It however does affect "If you have used a Minion skill recently"

Comment: Is it still affected by nodes that increase the duration of skills? Or do none of the passive nodes affect it since its a skill provided by an ascendancy?

Comment: Yeah, none of the nodes for skill duration affect it, but ironically enough (in what may be a developer error), Steelskin lab enchants do affect Bone Armour